# Inner Class access to Outer Class members

Tags: c++

I'm very confused about this topic, basically I've this code:

```
template <typename T>
class SListArray
{
public:
    class const_iterator
    {
    public:
        const_iterator(size_t i_currentNode = -1)
            :m_position(i_currentNode)
        {
        }

        T const& operator*() const
        {
            return m_data[m_position].element;
        }

        // ...

    protected:
        size_t m_position;
    };

    explicit SListArray();

    // ...

private:
    std::vector<Node<T>> m_data;

    // ...
};
```

This code give me a compiler error, so, I would to know if is possible to give the Inner Class the acces to the members of the Outer Class.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can inner classes access private variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486099/can-inner-classes-access-private-variables)

Answer (score 10):

Nested classes already have access to the containing class's members, *assuming they have a pointer/reference to the containing class upon which to operate*. Your iterator will need to store a reference to the outer class in order to be able to access the container as you appear to want.

Also note that protected data is usually a code smell and should typically be avoided. Prefer private data and a protected interface if appropriate.

EDIT: Unless this is strictly an exercise to learn how to program a container, just use one of the C++ standard containers such as `vector` which are well developed, debugged, and optimized.

Comment: Yes, as I say to Nawaz, it's an exercise. Regard the protected data, it's so because I've an iterator class that inherits from const_iterator.

Comment: @enigma Are you sure that relationship represents substitution? It seems that in the long term inheriting your iterator from const_iterator may cause more problems than it solves in the short term.

Comment: The non-const iterator can (or even should) derive from the const_iterator. Usually that way it's much easier to compare non-const and const iterators, assign a non-const iterator to a const-iterator, and so on. And it's a proper substitution: everywhere where a const_iterator can be used, a non-const iterator can also be used.

Comment: I wish you'd spelled out how to get hold of the containing class. In the iterator constructor `this` refers to the iterator, not the containing class. And I can not add parameters to the constructor because then range-based iteration doesn't work. I think.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use a friend declaration.

```
private:
  std::vector<Node<T> > m_data;
  friend class const_iterator;
```

**Update**: Oh, and your access to `m_data` is wrong. The inner class cannot access the members of the outer class without a pointer to an instance of the outer class. So you have to adjust your `const_iterator` class to store a pointer/reference to the outer class, and use this pointer/reference in the `operator*()`.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear. And  yes, in my code, the access to m_data is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

As Sjoerd already answered, you can give the access by using `friend` keyword. However, if you are looking for Java-style inner classes, there is no such thing in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Although making `const_iterator` a friend of `SListArray` would solve your problem, but I'm wondering why don't you use `std::vector` . Why yet another new generic class?

If you're looking for a new name, then you can `typedef` as:

```
typedef std::vector<Node<int>>                 NodeList;
typedef std::vector<Node<int>>::iterator       NodeIterator;
typedef std::vector<Node<int>>::const_iterator NodeConstIterator;
```

Comment: Your observation is correct. But I'm just implementing a Singly Linked List in different forms, for exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a reference:

```
class const_iterator {
public:
   const_iterator(ListArray<T> &arr) : arr(arr) { }
private:
   ListArray<T> &arr;
};
```

And then you need the friend stuff too.