# How to access the outer class object from the inner class in c++

Tags: c++, inner-classes

I am trying to access the outer class variable `cell[i][j]` from the inner class method `iterateForward`.

I do not want to pass `this` of outer class to `iterateForward` as `iterateForward(Matrix&)` , since it will add a parameter to iterateForward.

Inner class Method:

```
Pos Matrix::DynamicCellIterator::iterateForward(){
                    ....................
         (Example)    outerRef.cell[i][j].isDynamic = true;          
                    .....................
                    }
```

Here is my class:

```
 class Matrix { 
       class DynamicCellIterator{
            Cell* currentCellPtr;
            Matrix& outerRef;  //This will be the key by which i'll get access of outer class variables
        public:
            DynamicCellIterator(Matrix&);
                Pos iterateForward();
        };
        Cell cell[9][9];
        DynamicCellIterator dynIte(*this); // I have a problem of initializing the outerRef variable.
        Error errmsg;
        bool  consistent;


    public:
        Matrix();
        Matrix(Matrix&);
            ................
    }


//Here I tried to initialize the outerRef.
    Matrix::DynamicCellIterator::DynamicCellIterator(Matrix& ref){
        this->currentCellPtr = NULL;
        this->outerRef = ref;
    }
```

How can I initialize `outerRef`?

Comment: Not sure what error you're getting, but I'd write it Matrix::DynamicCellIterator::DynamicCellIterator(Matrix& ref):outerRef(ref){

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can inner classes access private variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486099/can-inner-classes-access-private-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize member references in the constructor's initialization list. And do the same for the `dynIte` member: initialize it in outer's constructor.

Something like this:

```
class Outer {
    class Inner {
        int stuff;
        Outer &outer;

        public:
            Inner(Outer &o): outer(o) {
                // Warning: outer is not fully constructed yet
                //          don't use it in here
                std::cout << "Inner: " << this << std::endl;
            };
    };

    int things;
    Inner inner;

    public:
        Outer(): inner(*this) {
                std::cout << "Outer: " << this << std::endl;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Have the constructor of the inner class accept a pointer to an object of the outer class and store it in a data member for later use. (This is essentially what Java does automatically under the hood, btw.)

Comment: I tried this only. But i am getting error in this line. `DynamicCellIterator dynIte(*this);`

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT: You need to look up initialization lists.

Comment: @DeadMG could you tell me `DynamicCellIterator dynIte(*this);` is invalid? Though I know `this` pointer will be used only in functions, I need to know, how logically `DynamicCellIterator dynIte(*this);` is invalid and how it is valid in initialization lists.

Comment: Show us the constructor of `DynamicCellIterator`.