# C++ -- Using a class' elements from a nested class?

Tags: c++, visibility, nested-class

Okay so I have a class, LinkedList, with a nested class, LinkedListIterator. Within LinkedListIterator's methods I reference the private fields of LinkedList. Which I thought was legal. But I get the error:

```
from this location
```

every time I reference them.

And I get corresponding error messages on the fields in the enclosing class:

```
invalid use of non-static data member 'LinkedList<int>::tail'
```

Any idea why? The relevant code is below:

```
template<class T>
class LinkedList {

    private:
        //Data Fields-----------------//
        /*
         * The head of the list, sentinel node, empty.
         */
        Node<T>* head;
        /*
         * The tail end of the list, sentinel node, empty.
         */
        Node<T>* tail;
        /*
         * Number of elements in the LinkedList.
         */
        int size;

    class LinkedListIterator: public Iterator<T> {

            bool add(T element) {

                //If the iterator is not pointing at the tail node.
                if(current != tail) {

                    Node<T>* newNode = new Node<T>(element);
                    current->join(newNode->join(current->split()));

                    //Move current to the newly inserted node so that
                        //on the next call to next() the node after the
                        //newly inserted one becomes the current target of
                        //the iterator.
                    current = current->next;

                    size++;

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
```

Comment: When asking questions that involves compilation or linker errors, it helps to post _all_ of the error messages, as complete as possible. I.e. just copy-paste them verbatim into the question.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486099/can-inner-classes-access-private-variables

Comment: @jogojapan completely different question, but the answer show that the inner class has a reference to an outer class instance, which is a way of going about solving this problem.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore In particular, that other question (and its answers) explains that instances of inner classes can't use members of the outer class as if they were their own members. Hence the basic underlying assumption of the question above is wrong. (To be clear, I didn't say the other question is a duplicate or anything.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just use non-`static` members like that. I think the following example will clear things out:

```
LinkedList<int>::LinkedListIterator it;
it.add(1);
```

What would `current` and `tail` be inside the method? There's no instance of `LinkedList` to speak of, so those members don't even exist yet.

I'm not saying make the members `static`, that would be wrong, but re-think your approach.

Look into how `std` iterators are.