# C++ nested classes, access fathers variables

Tags: c++, class, nested, parent

The title already says a lot,

but basically what i want to do is the following(Example):

I have a class called A, and another class inside a called B, like so:

```
class A
{
   int a;

   class B
   {
      void test()
      {
         a = 20;
      }
   };
};
```

As you can see my goal is for class B to have access to class A, as it is a nested class. Not this wont work, because B doesn't have access to A, but how can it get access?

Thank You

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Despite that you declared class B inside of A, classes A and B are still completely independent.  The only difference is that now to refer to B, one must do A::B.

For B to access A's stuff, you should use composition or inheritance.  For composition, give B a reference to an object of A, like so:

```
class B {
public:
  B(const A& aObj) : aRef(aObj) {
    cout << aRef.a << endl;
  }
private:
  const A& aRef;
};
```

For inheritance, something like this:

```
class B: public A { // or private, depending on your desires
  B() {
    cout << a << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, B would no longer be nested in the example above. Otherwise an object of type B would contain an object of type A which would contain an object of type B...

Comment: Your code for class B(the first block) doesn't give any sense for me... The constructor's brackets.

Comment: Thanks, but there's only one problem now, whenever i try to access a member of a, it just gives me an error: cannot convert const typea to type a(simple version)

Comment: First, can you make A's methods const? If so, do it. Otherwise remove const-ness from the reference declaration. I added it because it's good practice, but it may be too restrictive for you.

Comment: I tried the first approach (composition) and ran into a serious problem - what happens if an outer (A) object is copied or moved?  Then the inner (B) object has a dangling reference to the old object.  I fixed the problem by avoiding this construct entirely - I pass an explicit reference to the outer object to every inner object method that needs it.

Answer (score 2):

The inner class is not related to the outer class in C++ as it is in Java. For an instance of `A::B` to access a member of an `A` object, it needs to have an instance of `A` somewhere, just as if `B` were not a nested class. Instances of `A::B` do not have any implicit instance of `A`; you can have many instances of `A::B` without any instances of `A` existing at all.

Pass an instance of `A` to `test`, and then use it to access the `a` member:

```
void test(A& a_instance)
{
  a_instance.a = 20;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Classes are types, types don't have data. Instances have data, but an instance of `A` does not (in your example) contain an instance of `B`, and the instances of `B` don't have any knowledge of any instance of `A`.

Answer (score 0):

Choices

- have `B` be a child of `A` instead of contained by `A`
- have `B`'s constructor take a ref to the `A` instance which created it (preferred)

Now, if the variable `a` is private this still won't help. You will either need an accessor a or a friend relation.

Answer (score -1):

C++ nested classes are not like java nested classes, they do not belong to an instance of A but are static. So a doesn't exist at that point