# How to access static int from nested class?

Tags: c++, class

How can I access a1, and a2 from c1::c2::func?

```
class c1
{
    public:
    class c2
    {
        protected:
        static void func();
    };

    public:
    static int a1;
    private:
    static int a2;
};



void c1::c2::func()
{
    int f1= c1::a1; //works
    int f2= c1::a2;

    c1::a1= 1;  //fails
    c1::a2= 2;

    printf("func"); 
}
```

error:

> prog.cpp:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `c1::a1'
>   prog.cpp:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to`c1::a2'

http://ideone.com/nK75A6

Comment: You should provide the error code and description. It usually helps.

Comment: @Dennis http://ideone.com/nK75A6

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486099/can-inner-classes-access-private-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will be compiled successfully if you define the static data members.

```
int c1::a1;
int c1::a2;
```

As it seems that the compiler does not generate object code for statements

```
int f1= c1::a1; //works
int f2= c1::a2;
```

because variables f1 and f2 are not used then it does not bother that a1 and a2 were not yet defined.

Comment: Ok, I unerstand this but why     int f1= c1::a1; int f2= c1::a2;  works without definition? or this is problem of ideon compiler?

Comment: @mrgloom It is because variables f1 and f2 are not used. So it seems that the compiler simply does not generate the object code for these two lines.

Comment: last question: what if c1::a1 not static can I access it from c1:c2::func?

Comment: @mrgloom Yes the function can access private data members of the enclosing class. However they can be accessed using an object of the enclosing class.