# C++ How to access Collection member variable from Iterator (inner class) - and does it make sense?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I'm trying to write class similar to std::vector, which would contain an Iterator as inner class. For some member functions of Iterator I would like to access variables from my Vector class. For example when overloading operator++ I would like to check if index of Iterator doesn't exceed size of Vector (and if so throw std::out_of_range()). I've implemented this access to outer class variable based on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486099/can-inner-classes-access-private-variables). But for some reason compiler throws following error at me:

> error C2440: '': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'Vector::Iterator'

Here is minimal version of my code replicating the issue:

```
template <typename Type>
class Vector
{
public:
    class Iterator;
    Vector() : size(0), capacity(0), data(nullptr) {}
    Iterator begin()
    {
        return Iterator(this, 0);
    }
private:
    size_t size, capacity;
    Type* data;
};

template <typename Type>
class Vector<Type>::Iterator
{
public:
    Iterator(Vector& vectorRef, size_t index) : vectorRef(vectorRef), index(index) {}
private:
    size_t index;
    Vector& vectorRef;
};

int main()
{
    Vector<int> vec;
    vec.begin();
    return 0;
}
```

What would be the cause of this? And does it make sense to pass reference to Vector class like that? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `this` has type `Vector*` or `const Vector*` but your constructor is accepting a `Vector&` so no matching constructor is found.

Try with `Vector(*this, 0)`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still mixing up uses of pointers and reference sometimes. Dereferencing "this" didn't fix the issue, but I changed type of vectorRef to Vector*  and at least it's compiling. Going to test it now.

Comment: Ok. Tested it again and it works with dereferencing "this" like you suggested as well. Thank you again.