# Nested class accessing outer class attributes without passing reference

Tags: c++, class, oop, inner-classes

I have a nested class and I would like it to have access to the attributes of the outer class. I've seen this done on other SO topics ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486099/can-inner-classes-access-private-variables) and some others). However, they always give a reference to an object of the outer class to be able to do that. In my particular case, I would like to avoid using a reference and do it like that:

```
class OuterClass {
private:
    int _outerData;

public:
    OuterClass(int data) : _outerData(data) {}

    class InnerClass {
    public:
        InnerClass(){
           // Modify or access outerData in the constructor or other methods
           // without using InnerClass(OuterClass& OuterObj)
        }
        //Other methods
    };
```

I want to do it like that because in my code the user has access to this using a method like this:

```
OuterClass::InnerClass* OuterClass::NewInnerClass("I don't want to pass any input in here") {
    return new InnerClass("Input here is ok");
}
```

As you can see, I want the user to call the method without calling any arguments in order to be easier to use.

How can I achieve this type of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something but what's wrong with this

```
OuterClass::InnerClass* OuterClass::NewInnerClass() {
    return new InnerClass(*this);
}
```

and this

```
InnerClass(OuterClass& OuterObj) {
    ...
}
```

I don't understand why you say

```
// without using InnerClass(OuterClass& OuterObj)
```

and

```
return new InnerClass("Input here is ok");
```

Those two requirements seem contradictory to me. First you are saying the `InnerClass` constructor should not have a parameter, and next you are saying that it is OK for the `InnerClass` constructor call to have arguments.

Comment: I didn't want argument for my `InnerClass` constructor because I didn't want an argument here: `OuterClass::NewInnerClass()`. And since I dind't know how to do it that's how I expressed my needs. Sorry for the unclear indications.

Answer (score 0):

`InnerClass` is a class, not an object.  Its only relation to `OuterClass` is in the name lookup rules, but an instance of `InnerClass` has no relationship with any instance of `OuterClass`.  For your purposes, the fact that `InnerClass` is nested doesn't matter.  It's just a separate class.

If an instance of `InnerClass` needs to modify a data member or call an object method of `OuterClass`, it needs to be told which instance of `OuterClass` to use.