# Why does the derived class have access to the private field of the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, friend

```
class Base {
 public:
  class FirstBase {
    friend class Base;
    int x = 10;
  };

  class SecondBase : public FirstBase {
   public:
    SecondBase() : FirstBase() {}
    void t() { std::cout << FirstBase::x; }
  };
};
```

This code compiles and works, but I don't understand why it works. Can explain or cite sources to read?

I use gcc version 11.4.0 std=C++17

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/q/486099/4117728

Comment: note that the inheritance isn't essential for the example. You can make `x` a static member and `SecondBase` will still have access https://godbolt.org/z/zWxsYWjo5

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Base` is a friend of `FirstBase`, and `SecondBase` can access anything `Base` can access.

From the latest draft:
[class.access](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.access#general-2.sentence-1), item 2:

> A member of a class can also access all the members to which the class has access.

(Note that "nested" classes are members of the enclosing class.)

with the [footnote](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.access#footnoteref-103)

> Access permissions are thus transitive and cumulative to nested and local classes.

Note that the inheritance is irrelevant - this is also fine:

```
class Base {
 public:
  class FirstBase {
    friend class Base;
    int x = 10;
  };

  class SecondBase {
   public:
    SecondBase() {}
    void t(FirstBase fb) { std::cout << fb.x; }
  };
};
```

Comment: friendship is not transitive, aside from that, true enough.

Comment: @Deduplicator It can be, "to nested and local classes", as per The Standard.

Comment: I meant that being friend of friend doesn't mean anything.

Comment: @Deduplicator Nobody said that it does. *Access permissions* are transitive in the situations specified in the standard.

Answer (score 17):

Because `Base` is a friend of `FirstBase`. So inside `Base` you can access everything in `FirstBase`. And `SecondBase` is inside `Base` so `SecondBase` can access `FirstBase`. If you remove the friend relationship or you move `SecondBase` outside of `Base`, it'll break immediately as you expect.

```
class Base {
 public:
  class FirstBase {
    friend class Base; // This vill give access to FirstBase private members inside Base.
    int x = 10;
  };

  // SecondBase is inside Base so you can access FirstBase private members due to the friend relationship
  class SecondBase : public FirstBase {
   public:
    SecondBase() : FirstBase() {}
    void t() { std::cout << FirstBase::x; }
  };
};
```